# ScpCfHttpDestination not available in cloudplatform-connectivity-3.3.1.jar

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am trying to use ScpCfHttpDestination from cloudplatform-connectivity-3.3.1.jar, but it does not seem to be available in versions from 3.0.0 to 3.3.1. Am I missing somehting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the class in dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudplatform-connectivity-scp-cf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Or even better within (more generic, transitive) dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>scp-cf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I would also suggest to create a new (temporary) project from the archetype to determine which dependencies work best for you.